# How to convert BMP image file to text file in VB

Tags: vb.net, image, data-conversion

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Dim OpenFileDialog1 As OpenFileDialog
    'If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
    'PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    'End If
 Dim openFileDialog1 As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog

    ' Set filter options and filter index.
 openFileDialog1.Filter = "BMP Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
 openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1

 openFileDialog1.Multiselect = True

    ' Call the ShowDialog method to show the dialogbox.
 Dim UserClickedOK As Boolean = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog
 PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName)
 End Sub
 End Class
```

With this piece of code I'm able to track  and open image. Now I want to access data of image and want to display. For this I have to convert image to text file. How is it possible?. In `C#` there is function called `Readimage`. What function will help me to read image in VB?

Comment: You can't convert a bitmap to a text file, unless it is ASCII art! http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/ASCII_Panzer_unt_Sattelzug.png

Comment: Yes, he can by reading it into a Byte array and then creating a .txt file with that content. But the content of the text file will be completely unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `File.ReadAllBytes` that opens a binary file, reads the contents of the file into a byte array, and then closes the file.

```
Dim data() as Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(path)
```

Comment: Is it possible to read using other functions like readline,readtext etc.

Comment: Not at all. These functions won't accept a bitmap file. Please accept the answer and upvote if it helped you :)